Getting numbers from matrix image using pytesseract
I am trying to retrieve the text from an image that is a matrix 4x4. The text are numbers. Although I was expecting the numbers all I got was: BE, 8, EEE, BE. The image is attached here: image
Anyone have an idea to solve this?
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

def preprocess_image(image_path):
   
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    return binary

def find_cells(binary_image):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(contour) for contour in contours]
    bounding_boxes = sorted(bounding_boxes, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))

    return bounding_boxes

def extract_text_from_cells(image_path, bounding_boxes):
    image = Image.open(image_path)

    cell_texts = []
    for box in bounding_boxes:
        left, top, width, height = box
        right, bottom = left + width, top + height

        cropped_image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))


        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_image, config='--psm 6')
        cell_texts.append(text.strip())

    return cell_texts


image_path = r'C:\Users\Sandro\Desktop\BINGO\screenshot.png'

binary_image = preprocess_image(image_path)

cells = find_cells(binary_image)

texts = extract_text_from_cells(image_path, cells)

for i, text in enumerate(texts):
    print(f"Texto da célula {i+1}: {text}")


Hello, did you install pytesseract using the command pip install pytesseract. Can it get results if use other images? Or try changing the --psm 6 in the pytesseract.image_to_string to 8.

From what I understand from your problem, you only want to read number
You can specify a config to pytesseract so that it only recognize numbers (Or, more precisly, tries to see if it recognize number; it could read a letter as a number, but you only have number so that's not a problem for you)
Example of config you can use :
config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'

--oem 3 means that you don't care how long processing take, you just want "the best result"
tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 is pretty self explanatory, you only recognize numbers
you can use it like that in your code
def extract_text_from_cells(image_path, bounding_boxes):
    image = Image.open(image_path)

    cell_texts = []
    for box in bounding_boxes:
        left, top, width, height = box
        right, bottom = left + width, top + height

        cropped_image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

        config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_image, config=config)
        cell_texts.append(text.strip())

    return cell_texts


I will try that, but I guess I already tried it. I will reply as soon as I test this approach. However, the image looks very straight forward to get the numbers, without noise. I thought it would be easier. Thanks

Hello, can you detail what kind of effect you need? In many cases, pytesseract doesn't recognize text, and we need to give it some hints.

I need the numbers of that image. the numbers will change over time in value an position. I already tried several configs with pytesseract but they all gave bad result. However, I read somewhere in a forum, that tesseract reads well the text if the text height is between 20 to 30 px. I still did not try that. Also, if I get no luck, I will try EasyOCR.

You can try scaling the image by a higher multiplier to see if you get the desired effect.
